# SQL Server statistics to RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, sql-server-2016

Me and my team we're building a metric environment in order to meaure every process around our business logic.

We wrapped most of our code with custom code in order to get code stats in RabbitMq and then we send it to a data collector like ElasticSearch in order to make some useful dashboards on that metrics.

We were wondering if there is any connector/standalone software that sends SQL Server 2016 statistics (query stats, locks, waiting commands, latches, ecc...) directly on a RabbitMQ queue.
Any related idea or suggestion on this topic is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is not. However, have a look here: http://www.nielsberglund.com/2017/02/11/rabbitmq-sql-server/ to see how you can use SQLCLR to connect from SQL Server to RabbitMQ.